# Elastic search any query execution platforms

Tags: elasticsearch

I am not getting it by searching. I think my search terms are poor. Is there any way to execute a search just passing the JSON doc for DSL.

Please refer [example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#query-filter-context-ex)

It requires every string needs to be enclosed by double quotes. Is there any way where I can just pass the below to get the data?

```
{
 query:{
  match:{title:"value"}
 }
}
```

Or any tool where I can perform some sort of CRUD operations.

I am looking something similar to Robo3t for mongo, sqlDeveloper, solr admin UI[where we can query].

Comment: you can directly hit them using any rest client, like postman etc

Comment: I commented the same @OpsterElasticsearchNinja in your answer

Comment: yeah, just saw that and commented there as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Elasticsearch API supports the JSON format and you can very much directly call the search endpoint by directly providing your search JSON.

Please see the endpoint POST `/your-es-server:port:/_search` and paste your search JSON in the body as shown in the example.

Refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html for more info, note using `GET` is not supported in some DSL, so on the safe side always use `POST`

Comment: Thanks. Then tools like `postman` would be useful. So don't we have any other tool or UI?

Comment: @Gibbs, you can use the kibana developer tool as well if you kibana, but I like postman, no exta installation and no extra n/w hop :)

Comment: I will explore `Kibana`. Thanks Ninja

Comment: @Gibbs, if you are just using elasticsearch and don't have any requirement of kibana, i would strongly suggest to simply use postman as the reason mentioned above :)